# c# click button web browser visual studio

Tags: c#

I hit another bump

```
webBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("submit_button").InvokeMember("click");
```

When it runs the button moves in the browser but it still do not work, I have to click the button twice that runs the code then it works

I tried using

```
webBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("submit_button").Focus();
webBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("submit_button").InvokeMember("click");
```

still not working

I think I need some kind of double click instead of only clicking once

Answer (score 1):

As long as you are sure you have the proper ID for the element then the issue may just be that the "click" member is being invoked before the page has loaded.

Try this to be sure the document is loaded:

```
if (webBrowser1.ReadyState==WebBrowserReadyState.Complete)
    webBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("submit_button").InvokeMember("click");
```

If it is a double click that you need, possibly try invoking the click twice with a sleep in between of a couple seconds? It is not the cleanest method though..

Comment: dident work, but what would fix it is some kind of waiting system before the click goes of, cause the information is applied to fast

Comment: Are you saying after the first click goes off for the double click or just in general?

Comment: what happens is that when it clicks it shakes the button then i click the generate button and then it works, so i have to press once then wait a couple of secounds then press again, so i would need like a timer

Comment: Do you have an approximation of how long you need in between clicks?

Comment: no i just click twice, do you have skype would be easier to talk over if u can